# What is Tanium spyware, what information does it collect, and how to disable it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, privacy

a company put some spyware on a brand new laptop that is causing the battery life to be about half that of a 3-year old Macbook Pro. I need to disable this junkware/spyware temporarily. Is there a good way to do that? What is it (Tanium) recording anyway? Cheers.

Comment: Sounds to me like the best way to disable it is to not use the company's computer for personal business you want to keep personal.

Answer (score 4):

Tanium does not have a keylogger although it does have the ability to read your website history or install a keylogger.

"Systems Management" allows large enterprises to inventory, track and control the millions of dollars they spend on equipment. You work for your employer and they "lend" you their laptop for you to use to help them do business.

Answer (score 3):

Mr. Google sends you to the [Tanium](http://www.tanium.com/) website, where you will find Tanium is a systems management tool for enterprises. If you want to disable it, you'll probably need to contact the IT department that put it on the machine in the first place. The software is put on to enforce company policy and allow the IT department to monitor and control the laptop. An off-switch that is easy to activate tends to defeat the purpose of the software.

Comment: "Systems management" is a euphemism that means there's a keylogger that records your passwords and that it records every website you go to. It's spyware that should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

De-Installation procedure (use `sudo -s` to get admin privleges)

```
# stop tanium system service
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.tanium.taniumclient.plist
# remove tanium service to prevent startup on reboot
launchctl remove com.tanium.taniumclient > /dev/null 2>&1
# remove tanium service definitions
rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.tanium.taniumclient.plist
rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.tanium.trace.recorder.plist
# remove tanium client
rm -rf /Library/Tanium/
# remove residual tanium stuff
rm /var/db/receipts/com.tanium.taniumclient.TaniumClient.pkg.bom
rm /var/db/receipts/com.tanium.taniumclient.TaniumClient.pkg.plist
rm /var/db/receipts/com.tanium.client.bom
rm /var/db/receipts/com.tanium.client.plist
```